# Find area under inverse of a cubic function.

Tags: definite-integrals

$ N = 2^a × 3^b × 5^c $

And the fractional part of $ \sqrt{N} = 0 $

a ,b, c (natural nos.)  are the roots of cubic

$ f(x) = x³ - px² + qx -8 $

Find out the area bound by the curve $ f ^{-1}(x) $ , y = 0 and x= 8 .

> I found out that N must be a perfect square and given that a , b, c are roots of f(x) , product of roots is 8 by theory of equations and since a ,b,c are even natural numbers, a=b=c = 2 but I am unable to proceed further